# Define user variables to use in a SQL that has an "in" statement in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to use defined variables in MySQL Workbench.
I am using version 6.3 of Workbench.
I am trying to run ad hoc queries that can have a value or multiple values:

If I have a single value, the query runs okay

```
set @Zdept_Id="548"
```

and then

```
Select *
from employees
where dept_Id in (@ZDept_Id)
```

but if I want to execute this for multiple departments, the query only returns values for the first number

```
set @Zdept_Id="548,221,1973,905"
```

and then

```
Select *
from employees
where dept_Id in (@ZDept_Id)
```

`Dept_Id` is an integer.

PS. These are reports that I run once a month, so automating them is not an option due to cost/benefit.

Comment: A variable value is ONE value. So you obtain `Select * from employees where dept_Id in ('548,221,1973,905')`, not `Select * from employees where dept_Id in (548,221,1973,905)` or `Select * from employees where dept_Id in ('548','221','1973','905')`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
SELECT *
FROM employees 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(dept_Id, @ZDept_Id);
```

Comment: @Vérace In Russian there exists a word which means both "to take away" and "to rob", and the difference is in context only...